# How can I put multiple photos, overlapped into a 3D image with the ability to slide to different depths - In Python

Tags: python, 3d, photo, modeling, overlapping

PhD student in medicine here, extreme novice when it comes to the world of programming! I'm using Vectra Polaris technology to acquire regions of interest in cancer tissue (FFPE blocks). I have serial cuts of the blocks and have taken images of them.

I want to over lap the imagines into a 3D model, and put in a slide bar, so i can slide to different levels in the tissue. Very similar to this (https://plot.ly/python/visualizing-mri-volume-slices/) - (slices in volumetric data), I also want to do this in Python as its a language i'm slightly familiar with.

Like I said, i'm a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated.
- Tyler